# Use Protractor browser.driver as a variable

Tags: protractor

I'm using page object model and I'm stuck at how to put the `browser.driver` elements as a variable.

Here is an example of using it with `Protractor`'s `element`:

```js
var Messages = function() {};

var messagesLink = element(by.css('a[href*="/Messages"]'));

Messages.prototype.visitPage = function() {
  messagesLink.click();
};

exports.Messages = new Messages();
```

Then I can use `Messages.visitPage();` throughout my test. The problem is when I try to do the same thing with `browser.driver`:

```js
var Login = function() {};

var usernameField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('UserName'));
var passwordField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password'));
var signOnButton = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[value="Sign On"]'));

var registeredUserName = 'user';
var registeredUserPass = 'pass';

Login.prototype.loginAsRegisteredUser = function() {
  loginAs(registeredUserName, registeredUserPass);
};

var loginAs = function(userName, pass) {
  usernameField.sendKeys(userName);
  passwordField.sendKeys(pass);
  signOnButton.click();
};

exports.Login = new Login();
```

The test instantly fails before even starting, throwing this error `NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: *[id="UserName"]`. The reason why I'm using `browser.driver` is because I'm accessing elements on a non-angular page. I want to try and keep angular and non-angular references separate from each other.

I'm not sure how `Protractor` handles this but in `Selenium` I can use the variable like so, `static By cancelButton = By.id("cphMain_btnCancel");`.

So, is there anyway that this can be done using `Protractor`?

Spec File:

```js
var home = require('../../pages/home/Home.js').Home;
var headerHome = require('../../pages/home/HeaderHome.js').HeaderHome;
var login = require('../../pages/Login.js').Login;

describe('Registered User | DEV_Smoke |--- Home page: ', function() {
  it('Navigates to the Home page', function() {
    home.visitPage();
  });

  it('Prints the current URL (see build.log)', function() {
    home.verifyHomeUrl();
  });

  it('Clicks Sign On link and signs in as a registered user', function() {
    headerHome.clickSignOnLink();
    login.loginAsRegisteredUser();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this could be because `element.` will execute when it is used ie when the tests are running whereas `browser.driver` will execute immediately.
I'm not sure i understand what you mean about your reason for using `browser.driver`

Comment: I get inconsistent errors when trying to access an element using `element` on a non-angular page. And for some reason the test fails on Firefox. Unless `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is not being triggered correctly...

Comment: can you share your spec file as well? Thanks.

Comment: Added it to the OP.

Comment: Good starting point thoughtworks - `https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to just wrap the findElement in functions and call them as needed

```
var Login = function() {};

var usernameField = function() { 
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('UserName')); //returns promise
}
var passwordField =  function() { 
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password'));
}
var signOnButton =  function() { 
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[value="Sign On"]'));
}

var registeredUserName = 'user';
var registeredUserPass = 'pass';

Login.prototype.loginAsRegisteredUser = function() {
  loginAs(registeredUserName, registeredUserPass);
};

var loginAs = function(userName, pass) {
  usernameField().sendKeys(userName);
  passwordField().sendKeys(pass);
  signOnButton().click();
};

exports.Login = new Login();
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!

But I'm interested in what @cnishina wrote and seeing if the changes I added to the OP change his answer. You did answer my question but I'm guessing his answer is the more recommended approach?

Comment: I thought you are looking for not using `element` for non angular pages since you are getting inconsistent behavior. If you are looking for a recommended approach then you would need to edit your question a bit I feel.

Comment: That is correct. You did answer my question. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

browser.driver is of type [`Webdriver`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L653) and when calling `findElement`, selenium-webdriver will try to evaluate wherever it is stated in your code. So prior to  your login method and possibly navigation to the login page, you are automatically looking for the WebElements for `UserName`, `Password`, and `input[value="SignOn"]`.

In your code snippet, it looks like you should use `element`. When using `element`, at runtime, the `findElement` will be evaluated. This allows for more reusable code.

For non-angular pages, you might have to provide your own syncing or some arbitrary sleep. This usually occurs with animations, long load screens, etc.

Also make sure you return your promises so the jasmine wrapper evaluates your function properly.

```
var usernameField = element(by.id('UserName'));
var passwordField = element(by.id('Password'));
var signOnButton = element(by.css('input[value="Sign On"]'));

// make sure you return your promises so the jasmine wrapper
// evaluates your function properly.
var loginAs = function(userName, pass) {
  return usernameField.sendKeys(userName).then(() => {
    return passwordField.sendKeys(pass).then(() => {
      return signOnButton.click();
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Oh man... looks like my whole project is incorrect then. I'm a little new to Jasmine and promises are still blowing my mind. I also updated OP with a spec file and added the page object in the login snippet. I don't know if that will change your answer.